# Button disappearing when in an HStack with a ScrollView

Tags: swiftui

When I create either an HStack or VStack that contains a Button and a ScrollView, the button doesn't appear. A space is made to the size of the button, but it is not visible. However, it does appear if I add that same button *inside* the scroll view (which isn't what I want). Is anyone else experiencing this?

Below is the code (I haven't implemented an action yet for the button)

```
struct CardView: View {
    var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 12) {
        OptionsButton()
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                OptionsButton()
                OptionsButton()
                OptionsButton()
                OptionsButton()
                OptionsButton()
                OptionsButton()
                OptionsButton()
                OptionsButton()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct OptionsButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {  }) {
            Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium))
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .clipShape(Circle())
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you show `OptionsButton` code?

Comment: @Asperi Updated!

Comment: Provided code works just fine by copy-paste (w & w/o scrollview). Tested with Xcode 11.4. Which Xcode version do you use?

Comment: @Asperi I went through my code line by line and discovered an animation was triggering it (it's a flip card and this is the view when the card gets flipped). I rebuilt it and now seems to be working fine, tough am unclear what the fix was. Maybe just a buggy XCode moment. Thanks for your help!